# Bash find fails to return all matching files when called from a script

Tags: linux, bash, hierarchy

Running the same command from the command line and from a bash script produces different results on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have a folder with the following contents:

```
├── audio
│   └── delete_me.mp3
├── words
│   └── audio
│       └── delete_me.mp3
│   └── images
│       └── delete_me.jpg
└── keep_me.txt
```

I have a bash script named `findKeepers.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

findKeepers () {
  local dir=$1
  echo "$(find $dir -type f ! -name delete_me*)"
}

findKeepers /path/to/directory
```

I expect it to output the path to the `keep_me.txt` file. Instead, I get a blank line.

If I run what seems to me to be identical commands from the command line, I get what I expect:

```
dir=/path/to/directory; echo "$(find $dir -type f ! -name delete_me*)"
/path/to/directory/keep_me.txt
```

---

If search instead for all files not called `keep_me`, the bash script ignores the audio folder. Here's another bash script called `findUnwanted.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

findUnwanted () {
  local dir=$1 
  echo "$(find $dir -type f ! -name keep_me*)"
}

findUnwanted /path/to/directory
```

Here's the result:

```
$ ./findUnwanted.sh
/path/to/directory/words/audio/delete_me.mp3    
/path/to/directory/words/images/delete_me.jpg
```

If I run the same thing from the command line, I get all three `delete_me` files:

```
$ dir=/path/to/directory; echo "$(find $dir -type f ! -name keep_me*)"
/path/to/directory/words/audio/delete_me.mp3    
/path/to/directory/words/images/delete_me.jpg
/path/to/directory/audio/delete_me.mp3
```

It seems to me that the bash script starts by going deep into the `words` folder, and then does not come out again to search adjacent folders or files. Is there something special about the `#!/usr/bin/env bash` environment that makes it do this? Or is there some other difference that I'm not seeing?

---

CODA: I'm guessing it was pilot error, because after more modifications it started working for me again. For anyone who is interested, the final version of my function is shown below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Returns 1 if the given directory contains only placeholder files, or
# 0 if the directory contains something worth keeping
checkForDeletion () {
  local _dir=$1
  local _temp=$(find "$_dir" -type f ! -regex '.*\(unused.txt\|delete_me.*\)')

  if [ -z "$_temp" ]
  then
   return 1
  fi
}
```

I use it like this:

```
parent=/path/to/parent/
for dir in $parent*/
do
  checkForDeletion $dir
  if [ $? = 1 ]
  then
    echo "DELETE? $dir" # rm -rf $dir
  fi
done
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, but the correct way to write your function is to quote the parameter expansions and the pattern argument, and *don't* capture the output of `find`: `findKeepers () { local dir=$1; find "$dir" -type f ! -name 'delete_me*'; }`

Comment: You might have different `nullglob` settings in interactive and non-interactive shells. That's a shell option that informs the behaviour when a glob doesn't match anything (which is only a problem in the first place because you don't quote the argument to `-name`). To check this, run `shopt nullglob` on the command line, and also put it in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your '!' is breaking the whole pipe. Try using '-not' instead, so your first code snippet would look like this:

```
  echo "$(find $dir -type f -not -name delete_me*)"
```

I am not that good at explaining where you should escape special characters and where not, but the fact that things work differently when using that outside function suggests that escaping may be the issue.